# Not able to register Event Grid subscription with webhook delivery properties in Azure

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-eventgrid

I have a REST service hosted in `Azure Web app`. I registered a webhook on `Azure Event Grid` by pointing to REST service endpoint. I have followed below link and added endpoint validation with Event Grid events in REST service. I am able to register webhook successfully.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery

But I am facing issue(Not able subscribe webhook) if I configure any `delivery properties in Event Grid` like Authorization or content-type headers as shown below. Please refer below attachment for error details(Shown right side of pic) as well.

[Event Grid subscription with webhook delivery properties failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK70C.png)

Could someone please help me on this.

Thanks in advance,

Ashok

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to check how event delivery is [authenticated with event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication#authenticate-event-delivery-to-webhook-endpoints).

Also, make sure that validation call is successful with event grid, Event grid supports two ways of [validations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery#endpoint-validation-with-event-grid-events).

1. Synchronous Validation
2. Asynchronous Validation

Subscription validation event example as below:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2d1781af-3a4c-4d7c-bd0c-e34b19da4e66",
    "topic": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "subject": "",
    "data": {
      "validationCode": "512d38b6-c7b8-40c8-89fe-f46f9e9622b6",
      "validationUrl": "https://rp-eastus2.eventgrid.azure.net:553/eventsubscriptions/myeventsub/validate?id=0000000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000000&t=2021-09-01T20:30:54.4538837Z&apiVersion=2018-05-01-preview&token=1A1A1A1A"
    },
    "eventType": "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent",
    "eventTime": "2021-00-01T22:12:19.4556811Z",
    "metadataVersion": "1",
    "dataVersion": "1"
  }
]
```

Refer to Webhook event delivery from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery)

Also check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/troubleshoot-subscription-validation) for troubleshooting validation issues